# Airflow: Get trigger date of DAG Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I schedule my DAGS daily but some dags run for 2,3 days also I have set `max_active_runs=1` which means exactly one dag will run at a time and other will be queued.

So is there a way to get exactly when my DAG was triggered and was queued?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this info from scheduler logs.
Search for DAG name and you will find state change and picking up DAG by scheduler.